# How to get data from an array using get_user_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom user profile field

```
<?php $basics = get_the_author_meta( 'fbasics', $user->ID ); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><input value="lesson1" name="fbasics[]" <?php if (is_array($basics)) { if (in_array("lesson1", $basics)) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } }?> type="checkbox" /> <?php _e('Lesson 1', 'gprofile'); ?></li>
        <li><input value="lesson2" name="fbasics[]" <?php if (is_array($basics)) { if (in_array("lesson2", $basics)) { ?>checked="checked"<?php } }?> type="checkbox" /> <?php _e('Lesson 2', 'gprofile'); ?></li>
    </ul>
```

I now need to use the data on the front end of wordpress to display information. I think I need to use the get_user_meta() function but I do not understand how to use is to get the value of an array.

How to get data from an array using get_user_meta()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$basics = get_user_meta($user->id,'fbasics',true);
```

if it also not works then change true to false so you'll get full user meta and `var_dump($basics)` to check if 'fbasics' really exists or not

Comment: That returns bool(false) what does that mean?

Comment: that's what i'm expecting because get_the_author_meta is also correct but i think there's no value saved as fbasics well first echo your $user->id did you get it and if yes then change true to false and print_r($basics) it returns you an array of all user value check if there's fbasics exists or not